# Does the Mojarra version correspond with the JSF version?

Tags: jsf, mojarra

For example, does Mojarra v2.1.29-redhat-1 imply that JSF 2.1 is being used?

I can't find definite info on that on https://javaserverfaces.java.net/

With other RedHat (and obviously also other vendors') products there is a disconnect between version numbers, for example between JBoss Enterprise Application Platform (EAP) and JBoss Application Server (AS), so I want to be sure.

If you know the answer, how did you arrive at it?

Comment: Do note that you're comparing apples and oranges there; JSF is a single framework and specification, the JBoss EAP is waaaaaaaay more than a basic enterprise server, its an entire platform consisting of many different technologies and specifications, including the AS. It is no wonder there is a disconnect between the versions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *Does the Mojarra version correspond with the JSF version?*

Yes.

- 2.3.x == JSF 2.3 implementation
- 2.2.x == JSF 2.2 implementation
- 2.1.x == JSF 2.1 implementation
- 2.0.x == JSF 2.0 implementation
- 1.2_x == JSF 1.2 implementation
- 1.1_x == JSF 1.1 implementation
- 1.0 == JSF 1.0 implementation

The same holds true for MyFaces, by the way.

---

> *If you know the answer, how did you arrive at it?*

The `Specification-Version` entry in JAR's `/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file and the API version in actual source code confirms it.